# How to animate the shape of an object based on two splines

Tags: animation, path

I want to animate a beam (a cone) between two splines: one defines where the beam comes out of, and the other where the beam hits (you can think of it as one ship pointing with a laser to another ship, while both are moving).

What would be the easiest way to do it?

[image: laser beam in red, in different times of the animation]

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something like this ...

[image]

... so here is the cone *Parented* to the moving *Cube* and for *Cone* object is set *Constraint* > **Track to** center *Cube*

---

In case you want the Cone to end at object's origin (or any specific point) you can, but it is a bit different solution ...

[image]

Instead of *Cone* ... parent a *Single Bone* to the moving *Cube*, parent the *Cone* to *Armature > Bone.* With *Armature* selected switch to *Pose* mode, select the *Bone* and assign *Constraint* > **Stretch to** center *Cube*.

---

Or ... for the same result (but without a bone) you can make it in opposite way ... parent the Cone to the center Cube (you just have to have Cone's origin at center of bottom face). In edit mode select Cone's tip vertex and search for **Add Hook**. It creates an Empty. Position the Empty at place of moving Cube you want the tip beam to start and parent Empty to moving Cube. For the Cone object Add Constraint > Track to moving Cube.

All versions are stored in collections ...
[image]

Comment: Brilliant in solution "Hook To" to set origin at circle end of cone, and hook the single tip vertex to empty following path!

Comment: thank you very much! this is exactly what i needed i'll try it!